# Strophe-Ejabberd-Rails: Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, ejabberd, strophe

I am getting the CORS error while trying to connect `xmpp server, ejabberd` running on port `5280` using `Strophe` on `Rails app`.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5280/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried the following ways to resolve the issue.

=> enabled cors for all domains in application.rb

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

=> Added `strophe.flxhr.min.js` but it gave another error `flensed is not
    defined`, which I wasn't able to resolve.

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `http://localhost:5280/` to `http://localhost:5280/http-bind` resolves the issue.

Comment: after installing several servers.. tweaking with dozen config files ... that was the answer! Thanks!